# Is e1 && e2 equivalent to e2 && e1?

Tags: c

Let `e1` and `e2`be two boolean expressions. Then, is `e1 && e2` equivalent to `e2 && e1` in C ?

My intuition tells me yes. By simple logic `A & B` is equivalent to `B & A`. Is this true in C as well?

Comment: @P0W: Remember short-circuit evaluation?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: What source are you using to learn C. Any C text book or tutorial should explain this in greater detail than we can explain here. (You can't learn C by asking about one operator at a time.)

Comment: We're using a subset of C, it's not very well documented unfortunately and I haven't gotten my hands on a C textbook yet

Comment: Why are there 6 answers that say the same exact thing?

Comment: Wouldn't a comment suffice? It doesn't seem constructive to dilute the answer pool simple because the standard wasn't quoted.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato Comments are not answers, there is always the debate about [deleting comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180325/help-us-figure-out-a-way-to-handle-the-explosion-of-comments-on-stack-overflow) over time which make me wary to put anything that I want to see stick around in a comment.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: In large part, it is because there were initial answers that were completely wrong and yet received votes up, so several people jumped in with correct answers. Even the answers that correctly stated the expressions were not equivalent omitted reasons why, so many people regarded the existing correct answers as unsatisfactory. StackOverflow permits people to edit answers, but some people are reluctant to do that, and some authors react poorly to editing of their answers. The currently top-voted answer was incomplete for a while and remains imperfect.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In general I am hesitant to edit answers unless it is to improve style issues ... I won't generally add content unless the account is no longer around or has been inactive for a long time. I have seen enough bad reactions that I think it is not worth it.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: because many of us answered at the same time. Welcome to SO, check out http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: I was here, same time would be a bit of a stretch... I think Eric's answer is more likely the honest one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Logically, yes.  `e1 && e2` will never have a different result than `e2 && e1` from a logical standpoint.

But from a code standpoint, if evaluation of `e1` or `e2` has side effects, then **no**, they are not completely equivalent.

Specifically, sometimes people use [*functions* in a chain of `&&`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18685788/111307).

```
if( isHungry() && hasFood() )  eat() ;
```

Usually you would want to put the *cheapest* to evaluation condition *first*, and only check the 2nd condition *if the first condition held up as true*.  **Short circuit evaluation** is what guarantees this will happen.  If the 1st condition in an AND logical operation *is false*, then the 2nd statement isn't even evaluated, because the end result won't be TRUE anyway `(FALSE && (TRUE && TRUE && TRUE && TRUE)) == FALSE)`.

In other words you wouldn't bother checking the fridge if you're not even *hungry*.

Sometimes people ***rely*** on the fact that short circuit evaluation will happen, and write code **that depends on it**.  This type of thing is shown in the comments below:

```
if( x && x->eval() ) { /* do something */ }
```

So, say `x=NULL` above.  What will happen?  An attempt to deference a null pointer? Should it be written as

```
if( x )
{
    if( x->eval() )
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I said heck no!  Short circuit evaluation means, if `x==0`, the right operand to the `&&` operator **would not even be looked at** in `if( x && x->eval() )`.  `x->eval()` would not be evaluated, and no null pointer exception would occur.

The other thing you have to watch out for is **if the functions you run in the if statement have a side effect**, such as incrementing a counter of some sort.  So, if **hasFood()** has an internal counter increment such as `fridgeCount++`.

In the even of short cct evaluation, the function will not even run, so any side effects you are expecting to happen when you hit the if statement, might not happen.

The OR operator also has short circuit evaluation, only in `if( e1 || e2 )`, the statement is short circuited to TRUE if `e1` turns up to be TRUE (then e2 is not even evaluated, the whole expression is considered as `TRUE`).

This behavior is true of C/C++, Java, JavaScript, PHP, Python, and many other languages.

Comment: The nominal result is equivalent, but the behavior is not equivalent in C. If the first operand to `&&` is false, the second operand will not be evaluated, and any side effects it has will not occur.

Comment: For example, `if (y != 0 && x / y == 3)` avoids dividing by zero.

Comment: Or if `e1` returns true, but has side effects that change what `e2` will evaluate to.

Comment: Side effects are not the only problem; the second expression could have other behavior that is undesired if the first expression is false, such as dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well, people use / __rely on__ short cct evaluation in code such as `if( x && x->eval() )` because it has this behavior.  If there were no such thing as short cct evaluation, it would be written as a nested `if( x ) { if( x->eval() ) }`.

Comment: @bobobobo: What is your point? I am not arguing against “short circuit“ behavior. Why did you revert my edit? This answer is incomplete without it: Side effects are not the only thing that makes `e1 && e2` different from `e2 && e1`.

Comment: @bobobobo: @Eric is right, but you two seem to agree conceptually anyway. Maybe it is a misunderstanding on terminology: `if ( x && *x = 1 ...` if the second operand were executed with `x` being `NULL` that would be undefined behavior, not a side effect. Executing code that invokes UB makes the whole program erroneous and this doesn't fall under the "side effect" umbrella. Maybe @Eric should have said "undefined behavior" instead of "undesired".

Comment: @LorenzoDonati: I used “undesired behavior” because I wanted to include implementation-defined behavior as well.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Right! IDB is also to be taken into account. Useful clarification indeed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil A situation like that sounds like incorrect code.

Comment: @bobobobo: You added an example of it to this answer. In `x && x->eval()`, `x->eval()` has undefined behavior if `x` evaluates to false. So the sentence that says the expressions are not equivalent if “if evaluation of `e1` or `e2` has side effects” is incomplete. It should include **all** undesired effects in `e2`, including undefined behavior and implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: In `( x && x->eval() )`, `x->eval()` [won't execute if `x` evaluates to false](http://stackoverflow.com/a/628538/111307).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but the evaluation is different. Let me point out an example where this matters.

```
e1 = (pStruct == NULL)
e2 = (pStruct->value != 0)
```

`e1 && e2` is acceptable, but `e2 && e1` will cause a segfault if `pStruct` is `NULL` because `&&` is evaluated left to right

Comment: It would be noted that the `=` shown in this answer means “stands for”, not assignment. `e1` and `e2` are not actual identifiers used in the code; they are just symbols used to discuss what is in the code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True. If this was code, we'd get a segfault when attempting to evaluate the `e2` assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If `e1` and `e2` are expressions without side effects and they are both valid independently, then yes this will be equivalent.

In practice, they may not produce equivalent results even if both expressions are without side effects due to short circuiting behavior:

```
// given some array X of 10 members
if (i < 10 && x[i] < 5) {

//... this is not 'equivalent' to:
if (x[i] < 5 && i < 10) {

// ... but obviously:
if (i < 10 && z > 15) {

// ... is equivalent to:
if (z < 15 && i < 10) {
```

So, for the general case of any boolean expression `e1` and `e2`: *no, they are not equivalent*.

For a given case: *yes, they may be logically equivalent.*

Comment: Sometimes they're equivalent; sometimes they're not. I'd call that *not equivalent*. `+` and `*` yield the same result when both operands are `2`, but it doesn't make sense to say that they "*may be equivalent*".

Comment: @KeithThompson: I'll add "logically" if that suffices (not sure how swapping two operators applies to the OP's question; so I won't work in your example).

Comment: Depends on how you add "logically", I suppose. In any case, other answers already cover this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.  But 99% (actually, probably much, much more) of the time, yes.

If you're only talking about the result, then yes.  However, if you're expressions contain an functions or assignment (or anything that can change the state of something), then you should know that C is clever about how it will evaluate the arguments to &&.

If the first expression to && (the left value) is false, the second expression (the right value) will NOT be evaluated.

For example, it is safe to do something like:

```
struct some_struct *x = NULL;
if (x && x->some_struct_value) {
    // Some code here
}
```

Since the left value `x` is evaluated as `false`, the right value `x->value`, which would normally crash your application, will not be evaluated, and your application will not crash.

Another example would be something like this:

```
int always_returns_false() {
    return 0;
}
int increment(*int x) {
    (*x)++;
    return 1;
}
int main() {
    int my_int = 0;

    if (always_returns_false() && increment(&my_int)) {
        // Stuff! (Or no stuff, doesn't matter!)
    }
    return my_int;
}
```

If you switch around the expressions in the conditional on 11, you could get a return status of either 0, or 1.

So, while logically, `(e1 && e2) == (e2 && e1)`, functionally, in C at least, they can cause different actions and outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

`e1 && e2` may not be equivalent to `e2 && e1` because of [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), so if these expressions have side effects this can cause different behavior. the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) in section `6.5.13` *Logical AND operator* paragraph *4* says:

> Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation;
>   there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first operand. **If the first operand
>   compares equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated**.

So the second operand will not be evaluated if the first operand is equal to `0`. So let's say that `e1` evaluates to `0` but `e2` evaluates to a non-zero value then in this case:

```
e1 && e2
```

then `e1` will be evaluated but `e2` will not but in this case:

```
e2 && e1
```

both `e1` and `e2` will be evaluated.